# Examine current messages in Django admin.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using Django 1.5, Python 2.7

Is there a way I can examine the messages that have been added to the message object in my `admin.py` file? In my admin model, I am overwriting the `save_model` function, and would like to stop a "model successfully changed" message if it doesn't meet certain criteria.

```
from django.contrib import admin, messages

class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('whatever', 'etc')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        # I want to look at messages right here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/messages/#expiration-of-messages).

Example:

```
from django.contrib import admin, messages


class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('whatever', 'etc')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        storage = messages.get_messages(request)
        for message in storage:
            # Examine message here.
            pass
```